# What's the difference between version control system(SVN as example) and CI server(Jenkins as example)?

Tags: svn, jenkins, version-control, continuous-integration

I read a lot of info.
But didn't get it.
As I see they make same things.
And we can you actually only one of that.

Comment: Google them separately and read, you will get the answer.

Comment: I told I read info about it. But still didnt get

Answer (score 2):

A Version control system (`SVN`) helps you manage and create meaningful sets of changes to the source code of your project, send those changes somewhere central so that you keep the history of changes safe, and makes it easy for other people in your team to get the history of changes in order to collaborate with you.

Where as continuous integration (`Jenkins`) system helps you build and test the source code of your project to see if it works without any errors, whenever you or your team mates make a changes.

A VCS is related to a CI system in that one usually sets up an automated process that links them, by triggering a build every time a set of changes lands into the VCS.

The CI system reports whether a build was successful or not on its own, but can also report back to whoever triggered the building process.

A build process can be triggered either by having the CI system  periodically poll the VCS for changes, or by having the VCS notify the CI system that there are new changes.

In short VCS helps to build your code and `Jenkins` helps to verify and validate your code.

Comment: @Oleg , please accept the answer if you are clear with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous Integration Tool - Tool that builds the software for each and every change that is done during development team

Version Control System - To track and record the changes that is happening during source code change for adding feature or fixing a bug.